# How to upload a solution from local system to a server accessible via RDP

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2013, publish, rdp

I've developed a solution and tested it. It's uploaded to Azure using the convenient method of publishing XML file. Now I realize that it's supposed to be put in on-premise local server (it's an internal application not requiring access to the Internet).

When I go to the server, I use the RDP to access a system. In there, I execute a connection to another RDP. The second system is the one hosting both SQL Server and IIS where the application will reside.

Is it at all possible to construct such a publish XML? If so - how? If not - what should I request form the IT department to open/install on the innermost RDP so I can shove in my stuff by the oh-my-god-I'm-so-lazy press of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install webdeploy on your host machine. With IIS and webdeploy installed you can use same publishing techniques as you did with Azure.

I think it goes without saying that you must have direct access to host. If it's on external network you have to open webdeploy's and IIS ports, if you do not want to open this externally I recommend VPN (maybe basic point-to-point) that will create direct *line* between your dev and host machine.